# Data storage in JSON/XML files along with MySQL Database is efficient?

Tags: json, xml, database

I searched a lot on **SO** & as well as on **Google**, but did not get an exact answer to my question. So, here is my question.

I am working on a project in which we are **storing our data in the database as well as in the XML files** from back-end **to reduce database load**. And, when we need that data on the front-end, **we call the respective XML files to fetch data**.

**Q.1 - I wanted to know, whether it is the best approach to reduce load on the database?**

And, I think JSON will be a better alternative to XML as it is light weight. So, my another question is,

**Q.2 - Is it efficient to use JSON to store data instead of XML?**

Also, we can introduce **memcache** to reduce the same load. But, *if data is not available in **memcache**, we have to query the database*. **In this case, can JSON/XML data storage come in handy?**

**Q.3 - Is there any other efficient approach?**

I have heard of Apache Cassandra & Hadoop, but it seems that it is good to use these when you are working on a highly scalable application. So,

**Q.4 - Is there any Apache Open Source project (for start-up scale) we can make use of?**

In short,

**Q.5 - What is the best way to *STORE & QUERY* the data in an efficient & performance oriented way?**

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking from database, I guess you mean a SQL based database. If you search a solution for storing data on your local device you have multiple choices

- SQL based data store

  You can use SQLite or SQL Server 2012 LocalDB to store data on your local drive in SQL format.
- NoSQL based data store

  If you want to store your data in XML or JSON format this would be your choice. I won't call a specific one, just search for 'NoSQL' and you'll get lucky.

It depends on your needs, but one simple advice:

> If you depend on performance, storage or other indicators, don't implement it by yourself. There are a lot guys out there that will program such software and are really good at it.

Comment: Thanx for ur reply. NoSQL is a good choice but do you think NoSQL alone will suffice? And, I wanted to know how we can make use of SQL & JSON/XML based structure to store & query our data. Like, most of the big companies do that i.e. they use SQL database along with Cassandra/Hadoop. But, what is the best way for a start-up to build such an architecture coz we don't know when our application may scale (keeping that in mind)?